# There is a little juice left in my glass. / I have a little juice in my glass

Tags: sentence-choice

> **There is a little juice left** in my glass.
>
> **I have a little juice** in my glass.

Which version for native speakers sounds more natural, or are they both fine?
For me, as a learner, the second version sounds a bit strange because of "I have ... in my glass." - A little juice contains in their glass, not in their pocket. That's why I prefer the first version.

Comment: They both sound equally natural to me. But I don't understand your sentence "A little juice contains in their glass, not in their pocket." It might be helpful to look up the word "contain" - you never follow it with "in" in the active voice.

Comment: They mean different things. Is "left" important? Or are you only asking about the difference between "There is..." and "I have..."?

Comment: @gotube, I asked about the difference in that context. Do you think "left" is unwanted here?

Comment: _Left_  implies 'I have drunk most of the glassful, but a little remains'. _I have_ refers to the fact that it's your own portion of juice that you are talking about. Either is natural. (You could use _left_ in the second version too.)

Comment: @Sergei The question is still asking how two unrelated changes affect the meaning. If you're only asking about "left", then make both sentences start the same way. Otherwise this is 2 or maybe 4 different questions. "I have ... left" isn't an idiomatic phrase. You can say, "There is ... left".